# Xacro files editing with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

Does someone know  if there exist a XACRO plugin for Eclipse.
I interesting in editing a relative complex robot model, So I really like to have some kind of code outliner and other editing devises.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48860/xacro-files-editing-with-eclipse/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been using the XML editor from the 'XML Editors and Tools' plugin for Eclipse. As xacro is 'just' XML, it has worked quite well for me.

The plugin can be installed from the 'Install new software...' item under the 'Help' menu. Select the appropriate update site for your Eclipse version ('juno' for me). Now type 'xml editor' in the filter box (above the treeview with plugins). After a short while the 'XML Editors and Tools' plugin should show up. Select, click next and follow the wizard.

Now just make sure to associate the XML editor with xacros by 'Content Type' (this can be done in the Preferences window of Eclipse).

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on 2012-11-22**:
Thank you ipso you helped me quite a lot !
I actually had already installed the XML editor but had no idea how to associate it with the xacro files.   now it works perfectly.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-11-22**:
No problem. Glad I could help.